# How to implement user authentication using ASP.NET Identity in a Winforms application

Tags: asp.net, identity

I have a WinForms application that accesses an Azure SQL database via a WiFi connection. I would like to know how I can use ASP.NET Identity to register and login a user with their username and password. I have seen how a sample ASP .Net MVC 5 project does most of the work for you but can't seem to duplicate the functionality in my WinForms app. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to accomplish this, I would start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx

One way is to use domain security, another way would be to use ASP.Net Membership by adding the necessary configurations to your app.config along with a reference to System.Web.  In your app.config you could use a SQL Azure connection string.